# Where should I ask Dynamics AX 2012 functional questions?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I'm a beginner in Microsoft Dynamics AX 2012 ***functional*** side (especially *finance* side).

On which site and how can I ask about my problem/issues related to the functional side of Dynamics AX 2012?

Comment: Functional as opposed to what?

Comment: Dear @This_is_NOT_a_forum , thanks for your comment. Functional I mean not technician side. I want to ask , discover user manual - keu eser manual. For example: how I can add setup to Fiscal side, or about Workflow setup ecc

Answer (score 2):

It looks to be on topic on https://serverfault.com/ as per https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic:

> Server Fault is for questions about managing information technology systems in a business environment.
>
> If your question is about:
>
> - managing the hardware or software of servers, workstations, storage or networks
> - tools used for administering, monitoring, or automating these
> - deployment to and management of third-party provided information technology platforms

You could also ask in their chat room https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127/the-comms-room if your question would fit on their site.